# Plotly - Dash unexpected EOF while parsing @app.callback

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, plotly-dash

I am following tutorial on Dash, working in VS Code. It gives me this error message `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. The tutorial showed the same problem as the sample code on callbacks that I tried from the Dash website (see below). I think the problem is not the code.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(input_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

It has a problem with this section

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
```

in particular with the last bracket. It shows this error message 
 `File "", line 4
    )
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

I have installed my virtual environment several times. The VS Code status bar shows `Python 3.7.7 64bit ('denv37:conda)` which is a correct virtual environment that contains among other things the following dash components

```
dash==1.3.1
dash-core-components==1.2.1
dash-html-components==1.0.1
dash-renderer==1.1.0
dash-table==4.3.0
```

They were installed from `requirements.txt.`file which came with the tutorial. I also tried to install `pip install dash==1.9.1` using different environment, same problem.
Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? I am completely new to this. Many thanks.

Comment: Your code is working for me. Try putting your code here: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php to see if you maybe have a non-printable character in it that breaks it.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, I checked that and it all looks fine. No hidden characters. It looks like there is a problem with the environment or the VS Code. Thank you for the link, this will be certainly useful for me in future.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, in Spyder. Everything is up to date. It feels like maybe a bug. I've typed and retyped and checked everything and no luck.

Comment: Are you running this in a notebook? The `@app.callback(...)` is part of the function definition `def update_output_div(...)` and should be kept togethere.

Answer (score 3):

The callback needs to be associated with a function. It can't be executed on its own like that.
It didn't work for me when I try to run it cell by cell in a notebook, but able to execute it as a whole.